# How to set left command to Guest VM and right command to Host OS?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, keybindings

I just set up an Arch Linux virtual machine on my MacBook Pro (El Capitan). My goal is, when inside the Arch VM, to use the left command key for anything VM related and the right command key for OS X commands.

I think I have some of this set up but not all my left command commands are working inside the VM. I set Arch up with a [Tiling Window manager called BSPWM](https://github.com/baskerville/bspwm). The majority of movement commands use the "Super" key which I believe to be the command key on Mac. Only some of the commands issued with <kbd>Command</kbd>-{something} are recognized.

For example, to focus in on a window (or app, terminal, etc) you press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> - this works but moving from window to window doesn't work using <kbd>Command</kbd>-{<kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd>}.

There is something overriding commands and I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Which VM are you using: Virtualbox, Parallels, VMware, something else? How dd you configure the key mapping in the VM itself (in the VM software, not in Linux)?

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox. Under VirtualBox > Preferences > Input > VirtualMachine I set the "Host Key Combination" to "Right Command".